# Are there problems with using the same name for an XML element and attribute?

Tags: xml

Can I do something like this?

```
<root>
  <element>
     <child element="foo" />
  </element>
</root>
```

and like this?

```
<root>
  <element element="foo" />
</root>
```

Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is nothing preventing you to do that in XML.  Nor at the XML Schema, XQuery or XSLT levels.  Two aspects to take into account though:

- what's the semantics of this?  Is it really what you want, does it really make sense?
- is it possible that one of the tools you will use will have some limitations in that regard? (none that I know of, but who knows, maybe one of those Java or C# *"XML binding tools"* that generate classes and fields based on the element and attribute names...)

Comment: I know that it doesn't really make sense but I'm interested just in technically accepted or not.
Thanks